# How to debug NullPointer with no trace to my code?

Tags: java, debugging, null

I have been working on a fairly large project and recently I have been null pointer expceptions with no trace to any code I have written at seemingly random times when testing the gui. I have no idea how to track down the cause of this, does anyone have any ideas of what kind of interractions would cause something like this?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1064)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1052)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.processException(EventDispatchThread.java:223)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:215)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Could be anything. Does your code always catch and log exceptions? Do you check for nulls everywhere they mufti occur in your code?

Comment: Can you replicate this error at will?

Comment: This is kinda bogus.  I think the exception handler isn't reporting full or correct information.  Use a debugger to look for thread groups that have an `UncaughtExcpetionHandler` set.  Normally the EDT reports an exception directly, I think someone is messing with the reporting mechanism.

Comment: Maybe you do something in a non-awt thread that tries to update your user interface. I had similar problems with jtable. This could be hard to find if your project is large. I would first try to find a hint where the exception rises.

Comment: It "could" be possible if you are manually generating events and pushing them into the queue

Comment: What version of java are you using?

Comment: Suppose you click a button and this exception throws up then check the code of the button click. Narrow-down your code, If you can't trace out the mistake, Put it up here. we'll help you out.

Comment: What information is provided in your stacktrace at line `Caused by:` and following?

Comment: ALWAYS post the ENTIRE, COMPLETE stack trace -- often the "Caused By" sections are the pertinent ones.